# Can I get the backup option of cp and mv to work with directories?

Tags: shell-script, backup, rename, cp

```
--backup[=CONTROL]
    make a backup of each existing destination file
```

The man page does say that it works on file. It doesn't seem to have any effect on directories. Is there anyway to make this work with directories as well? I want the destination directory, if it exists, to be backed up in the same way that a file would be backed up.

Comment: What does "work" mean for a directory?  Are you trying to back up the information about the directory itself, or are you trying to organize the backed-up files into a separate back-up directory (instead of having each file backed up in the directory in which it is found)?  Either way, "cp" will not do this for you; you need to write a script.

Comment: @IDAllen Yeah I have come to that same conclusion. Let me make the script an answer instead.

Comment: Note that moving a directory or file to a destination directory of the same name puts the directory or file into the destination directory. Is this a behaviour that you want to avoid so that `mv /some/path/name name` behaves one way if the source is a regular file (file `name` is put into directory `name`) and a different way if the source is a directory (directory `name` replaces the destination directory called `name`)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that there isn't, so I wrote this script which emulates the functionality:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -e "$target" ]
then
    backup="$target.bak"
    if [[ -e "$backup" ]]
    then
        count=0
        while [[ -e "$backup.$count" ]]; do let "count += 1"; done
        backup="$backup.$count"
    fi
    mv "$target" "$backup"
    echo "backup file $backup created."
fi

# Normal cp or mv follows
```

Comment: I think you've written an *archive and delete* script, not a *back-up* script, since your script deletes the original directory (by renaming it). Your script comment about "file created" will mislead if it isn't a file.  Depending on how you call your script (i.e. if you use it with `find`), you may find that it archives all the files under a directory before it archives the directory itself, or `find` will complain that you've just moved away a directory that it was about to walk - this may not be what you want.

Comment: @IDAllen You misunderstood, this script is to be used in place of `cp` or `mv`, to make the `--backup` behavior applicable to directories.

Comment: I suggest that you start using `rsync` instead of `cp` (and in many cases it can also replace `mv`). There are backup options including directories with `rsync`. In general, you can do *many* more things in order to copy, synchronize or backup with `rsync`. If you 'only' want to synchronize, please try `unison` (or `unison-gtk` with a GUI).