# mv --backup merging for directory rather than giving and increment nnumber

Tags: linux, mv

the command `mv --backup=t file file.backup20201119` causing the file to merge rather creating a separate file

Expectation

```
file.backup20201119
file.backup20201119 ~
file.backup20201119 ~1
```

Reality

```
file.backup20201119
```

This happens only for directory not for files

Comment: `--backup`  works for files only. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32397/can-i-get-the-backup-option-of-cp-and-mv-to-work-with-directories

Comment: Your example works perfectly for me. Create files `touch file file.backup20201119`. Now rename `file` to the same as the existing backup, `mv --backup=t file file.backup20201119`. Look at the result, `ls file*` → `file.backup20201119  file.backup20201119.~1~`. I don't understand your comment about a directory and files: where does a directory come in this? Please [edit] your question to make it clear

Comment: file no issue. issue is with directory. i mean directory is folder name